# Creating Verticle rhythm in google docs?

Tags: google

I have been reading the importance of verticle rhythm in web design, and I wanted to incorporate it into Google Docs.

To my knowledge there is no support for verticle rhythm presently in Docs.

Is there an add-on or a third-party application to help create it in Docs?

Comment: Vertical rhythm isn't something one uses a "plug in" for in my experience. It's far more about placement and appearance of headlines/subheaders, how images are used, etc. All of which requires manual decision making and adjustment.

Comment: I did find something relevant to creating a grid in the form of an add-on which was very helpful.
You can find it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/baseliner/agoopbiflnjadjfbhimhlmcbgmdgldld?hl=en-GB).

With a lot of trial and error, I came close enough to establishing a vertical rhythm to my document.
Hopefully it helps. :)